# assign value to a field in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes worker and company, say

```
class worker {
string name;
string company_id;
string company_name;
}

class Company{
string c_name;
string c_id;
}
```

Now, I want a linq, such that when company_id and c_id match, assign company_name to c_name. That is intially, company_name is null. I want to use linq to fill in the values.

Comment: do a join and project to Company

Comment: And? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public class Worker 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string CompanyId {get;set;}
    public string CompanyName {get;set;}
}

public class Company
{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Id {get;set;}
}


   var companyList = new List<Company>
    {
        new Company{Id = "1", Name = "Company 1"},
        new Company{Id = "2", Name = "Company 2"},
        new Company{Id = "3", Name = "Company 3"}
    };

    var workerList = new List<Worker>
    {
        new Worker{ Name = "Worker 1", CompanyId = "2" },
        new Worker{ Name = "Worker 2", CompanyId = "1" },
        new Worker{ Name = "Worker 3", CompanyId = "2" },
        new Worker{ Name = "Worker 4", CompanyId = "3" },
        new Worker{ Name = "Worker 5", CompanyId = "1" }
    };

workerList.ForEach(w => {
            w.CompanyName = companyList.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == w.CompanyId)?.Name;
        });


foreach(var w in workerList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(w.Name+"-"+w.CompanyName);
    // ==> output will be
    //Worker 1-Company 2
    //Worker 2-Company 1
    //Worker 3-Company 2
    //Worker 4-Company 3
    //Worker 5-Company 1
}
```

Or if the idea is to understand Join in Linq, then

```
var workers =   (from worker in workerList
                join company in companyList
                on worker.CompanyId equals company.Id
                select new Worker 
                 {
                    Name = worker.Name,
                    CompanyId = worker.CompanyId,
                    CompanyName = company.Name
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of `workers` and `companies`, and can iterate through them:

```
foreach (worker w in workers)
{
    if (companies.Any(c => c.c_id == w.company_id))
        w.company_name = companies.Where(c => c.c_id == w.company_id).Select(comp => comp.c_name).Single();
}
```